# Parsing date in pandas

Tags: python, date, pandas

I have the following date in my pandas data frame:

```
In[161]:df
Out[161]: 
0      {u'$date': 1460636422821}
1      {u'$date': 1460636466877}
2      {u'$date': 1460637197836}
3      {u'$date': 1460637271004}
4      {u'$date': 1375794726230}
5      {u'$date': 1375794000000}
6      {u'$date': 1374152400000}
7      {u'$date': 1376658000000}
8      {u'$date': 1377867600000}
9      {u'$date': 1375794000000}
```

When I tried to convert into date time

```
 pd.to_datetime(df.apply(pd.Series)['$date'],unit='ms')
```

I got an annoying error:

```
OutOfBoundsDatetime: cannot convert input with unit 'ms'
```

If I apply 'pd.to_datetime()' on a single entry (row), then it works fine. Any ideas how to avoid using loops for each row and get a normal output?

Comment: make sure that all your timestamps are in `milliseconds` - this error could happen if some of the timestamps are in `nanoseconds`...

Comment: @MaxU, this is what I think may happened here. Is there a way to ensure that all timestamps are actually in ms?

Comment: it's possible if you can specify a maximum year (it mustn't be very precise +/- 100 years is OK), that might occure in your data set - can you?

Comment: it should be no greater than 2016. I am a bit puzzled as I have an additional column from the same data, with exactly the same format ('ms') and it worked nicely. When I applied the same procedure to this data column, I got the error I showed. It works if I apply .to_datetime to each row separately, but if I run it on the entire column, it fails. any ideas?

Comment: check whether you have any timestamp greater than `1577836800` (2020-01-1)

Comment: I checked, and I don't have. The larges is 14..... I can send you the  entire column if it helps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145232/discussion-between-maxu-and-arnold-klein).

Comment: I hope you fix your issue with MaxU since I cannot reproduce your error. I'm using Python 3.5.3 :: Anaconda 2.4.0 (32-bit) and >>> pd.__version__
'0.19.2'.    df = pd.DataFrame(pd.to_datetime(df.apply(pd.Series)['$date'], unit='ms'))
print(type(df))  <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>.   What is your version of python and pandas?